# Why do I have to set params with javascript when I use modelAttribute in spring form?

Tags: ajax, spring, modelattribute

When I use ModelAttribute in the controller and in the spring form, If I do not set values at the js before sending ajax crud request, cotrollers modelattribute gets all values null, why?

I am using form input and set path as name but if I do not set name at js, controller gets null value.

Comment: Show us some of your code.

Comment: I used el.serialize() and that solved my problem